# Blackberry Messenger or Whatsapp API for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, blackberry, whatsapp

I want to know that is there any API available for Blackberry Messenger or Whatspp for C# or VB.net??

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp is currently bound to mobile devices that do have a phone number and doesn't provide a SDK

Regarding the Blackberry thing you might want to look at this post: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Product-Management-The/Blackberry-Messenger-HELP-C-C-C/td-p/1551543 From what is posted there it seems there is currently a similar limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about whatsapp api .net on github

https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAP...

I don't test it

and there is another api ( whatsapp api php )

PHP interface WhatsAPI for PHP by Dídac Pérez Parera:

https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet